# How to update Root view based on selection in detail view in split view based ipad App?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I have used Split view controller in which root view as well detail view both inherits table view. I want to update Root view based on selection in detail view how to do that? I dont want to add new navigation view in root view. Please help as early as possible.

Comment: Use this It may Help-
DelegateObject.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:new_root_view_Object,current_object, nil]; 

It will update your Root View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for UISplitViewController:

"Note: A split view controller does not provide any inherent support for managing the communication between the custom view controllers you assign to it. It is your responsibility to determine the best way to do that. However, the delegation pattern often works well for master-detail interfaces. To implement such a pattern, your master view controller sends messages to a custom delegate object whenever the selected item changed or some other relevant event occurred. The detail view controller would then assign itself as the delegate of the master and would use the associated messages to refresh its contents."

It clearly states that you have to design your application for such communications.

Comment: Ya.. actually based on selection in master view detail view changes well.
Considering my application the 1st detail view contains table view and when i select one row detail view takes image view... and i am inserting some settings of this image view (e.g list, show single image etc) in root view..
I have tried using begin update and end update properties bt still its not working...
thanks for your cooperation..

Comment: Sorry, but I couldnt quite understand you.

Comment: Hello raj, 
Actually you require to send current view object to other side or using delegates you can achieve this.. 
Now i can update my root view too based on selection in Detail view of split view.

Comment: Yes, thats what, it depends on how you design your application's communication modules.